# Radio Button If..Then..Else to display a word in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this homework I really need help with, as the textboox the class gave me is not helping at all. The assignment is ----

Each radio button’s Text property should contain the name of a different state; choose any five state names. The Display button should display (in one of the labels) the name of the capital associated with the selected state name. Code the button’s Click event procedure using the If...Then...Else statement. Be sure to code each radio button’s CheckedChanged procedure.

I have 0 programming experience and took this class so I can learn, but man is it really hard for me to get it. The teacher doesn't respond to questions about the assignments until after they are due and it's pretty much pointless as I miss the credit for it.

I've looked all over google trying to find out and example of this, but I cannot find any that don't require you to pay for an answer.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DisplayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radCarolina.Checked) = true t
    }

    private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I need the display button when clicked to show the different radio buttons capital in the text box, for example my radCarolina radio button is for North Carolina, and I need it to send "Raleigh" into the text box when I click display.

Answer (score 0):

You started right! add an event handler for the "Display Button".
Inside it, chain an if-elseif-else statement to find out which radio button is checked.
Finally, inside each statement of the if-elseif-else chain, change the displayed text.

**How to change a label text in WindowsForms:**
`labelIdHere.Text = "some text";`

**Also, checkout the proper syntax for if-elseif-else here:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing your .aspx page is something like this-

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radCarolina" runat="server" Text="North Carolina" GroupName="States"/>
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radCalifornia" runat="server" Text="California" GroupName="States" />
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radFlorida" runat="server" Text="Florida" GroupName="States" />

<br />
<asp:Button ID="Display_Btn" runat="server" Text="Display" OnClick="Display_Btn_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

So in your aspx.cs page, do this -

```
protected void Display_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if(radCalifornia.Checked)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Sacramento";
            }
            else if(radCarolina.Checked)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Raleigh";
            }
            else if (radFlorida.Checked)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Tallahassee";
            }
 }
```

`if (radCarolina.Checked) = true t` is not the correct syntax. Learn about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/if_else_statement_in_csharp.htm

Also it's very important that all the radio buttons have the same `GroupName`.
I recommend going through these videos for a proper understanding of ASP.NET - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo